# How to view text/rtf message part in .eml files which are ignored since Mail 6.0 upgrade?

Tags: mail.app, macos

I have a bunch of .eml files that contain the message part encoded as

```
Content-Type: text/rtf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline
```

Up to OS X Lion, Mail and Quick View both happily displayed the message.

The new Mail 6.0 included in Mountain Lion seems to ignore this part of the message and shows only a blank sheet (same for Quick View, of course).

Any ideas if that is intended or a bug and how I could resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in OS X Mavericks (10.9.x)